# Why search_analyzer (keyword) does not work with edgeNgram index_analyer?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```
analyzer:
    edge_ngram_analyzer:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: edge_ngram
tokenizer:
    edge_ngram:
        type : edgeNGram
        min_gram : 2
        max_gram : 20

productCode:
    type: string
    inxed_analyzer: edge_ngram_analyzer
    search_analyzer: keyword
```

Search string is `AH.20`
Index analyzer's tokens: `AH`, `AH.`, `AH.2`, `AH.20`
Search analyzer's tokens: `AH.20`

Query:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "product.productCode",
            "query": "AH.20"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But it returns nothing. What is wrong with the mapping?
PS when I don't use search_analyzer, elasticsearch returns correct results (I'm sure that ES breaks search string to tokens `AH`, `20` using `standard` tokenizer)

Comment: @AndreiStefan it does not work with term query/filter
    
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "product.productCode": "TA.WRN.020"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem, unless is a typo, is in your mapping definition:

```
inxed_analyzer: edge_ngram_analyzer
```

It should be:

```
index_analyzer: edge_ngram_analyzer
```

Comment: Yes, typo is a reason of this issue :( Thank you